# Memcache hash generation

Tags: php, hash, memcached

I got a sample Script which looks nearly like this:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host', 11211);
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host2', 11211);
```

If i use now

```
$memcache->set('var_key', 'some really big variable');
```

The key get/value get stored (only on one server), of course. But when i reorder the Memcache Serverlist, its recreating the cache. I noticed it always use the second Server... But why?

I just want to know and understand, how the hash for storage gets generated.
And which factors are relevant for the hash and server selection?

I could not find anything about.

Regards!

Comment: Sorry i forget always to accept an answer :) I just vote them up

Comment: How do you know its always picking the second server ? and what version are you using ?

Comment: I just tested it fast. I am using the latest client and server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is:

```
crc32($KEY) % Server.length
```

So in my case, i got 2 Servers with the Sample Key "var_key".

> crc32('var_key') % 2
>
> *The result is 0. So the first Server is the lucky one!*
>
> crc32('var_key_bit_longer_and_longer') % 2
>
> *In this case the second server (Result is 1) gets chosen.*

**As we can see, the following factors are relevant:**

- The Key
- Server count
- Order of Server

That's the way how the server gets chosen, for standard hash strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how the `hashing algorithm works` but client library may be implemented to run a CRC on the key and do a modulus over the number of instances in the list to select an instance from the list for the set/get

Better still you can increase the changes of each server been selected at `50-50` by using `weight`option

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host', 11211,true,50);
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host2', 11211,true,50);
```

Comment: Sure, but that doesnt say anything about the selection. It can not be random. There are some factors, which i dont know yet...

Answer (score 0):

Look at Cache::Memcached's [_hashfunc()](https://metacpan.org/source/DORMANDO/Cache-Memcached-1.30/lib/Cache/Memcached.pm#L841), it uses the key as its only parameter.

```
sub _hashfunc {
    return (crc32($_[0]) >> 16) & 0x7fff;
}
```

Comment: I dont think that the key is the only parameter and even if, that doesn't explain how the server get choosed.